# Windows Embedded Standard 7 won't find my .dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, windows-embedded-standard

Several weeks ago I have build a Native C++ .dll that wraps a third-party .dll to be used with C# P/Invoke in several applications to be deployed in WES7. I've been using Windows 10 as a dev box and everything works as expected. This week I finally got my hands on the box with embedded Windows and things are not doing that well anymore... I've tried to deploy three different C# applications that use the .dll I built alongside the third-party one but they all fail with a DllNotFoundException. Obviously both .dll files are in the same folder as my executable file for each project, but I keep getting the DllNotFoundException. My native .dll targets the Win32 platform, the embbedded windows is a 32-bit system, and all my C# apps are built to target the x86 architecture, so I've ruled that out. I've wasted the last hour messing around with the system32 folder to no avail, so I've run out of options. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: I just talked to a co-worker who works remotely and he had the exact same problem when trying to run our .dll under WES7. I'll update this question as soon as I have more info.

Comment: Could it be some support dll files not found? Probably not your dll but 3rd party one requires some?

Comment: Unless the 3rd-party .dll uses some other .dll that is present in desktop windows but absent in WinCE, that wouldn't be the case. Nonetheless, I'll investigate that

Comment: Is this a side-by-side error? It sounds like it.

Comment: No, I don't think so, it started happening even when I had only one application and these .dlls could only be found in this folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I happened to be dumb enough to deploy a DEBUG version in the target machine, which didn't have msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll. I used Dependency Walker to figure that out (apparently it was too hard for me to take a look at the project properties page drop-down) and deployed a release version in the target. It finally worked, but I had a different problem that leads to another question...